# Efficient way to store Shares of Posts in MongoDB on social networking site?

Tags: mongodb, share, social-networking, nosql

As the title states, say you have a Posts collection. Post has a userId (the author). Another user can share the Post. Posts also have tags, an array of ids of tags they are categorized as. How to store this for quick retrieval?

Use case: You have connections. You see posts from your connections, or posts shared by your connections. Posts have a "velocity" they are ordered by on the page. Shared post could either inherit and keep velocity of original, or live or die by its own velocity. Not sure what's best.

Options I've considered:

```
Post {id :uniquePostId, userId: authorId, shares: [userIds of those who shared], tagIds: [tagIds for post]}
```

Problem with this method: Mongo doesn't let you index two arrays. So the query is slow as hell if you want to query on both tagIds and shares. Indexing both separately results in almost a full table scan.

Another Option:

You duplicate the Post like so:

```
Post {id: uniquePostId, userId: user who authored or shared the post, original: {postId: the original postId, or null if this is it, userId: the author of the original post}}
```

Problems with this approach: Say you want to fetch 20 posts, so you query on userId in your connections, how do you deal with duplicate shares in your connections? Gets kind of ugly.

Other approaches I've read:

```
post: {
 shares_and_tags: [{type: share, id: 1}, {type: tag, id:4}, ...]
}
```

This seems to resolve the indexing problems, but I don't know enough about Mongo to know the performance implications here. Gonna do some testing shortly, but figured I'd see if the community has any advice or experience. Thanks!

Comment: What does "sharing" mean in this context? Similar to retweeting? As for tags, your third option is most efficient. Indexes on arrays provide very good performance.

Comment: In that case by far the most efficient route for your "sharing" is duplication. This is how Twitter works for example. When you post a message there it is stored in the stream of all followers rather than just in the "sent" stream of the sender. This may sound counter intuitive/inefficient but it allows for linear scaling and is much more "read" friendly.

Comment: Awesome, could you please elaborate on Twitter's design for retweets some more? That sounds like an excellent design and more information would be really helpful. I've searched for how twitter handles retweets and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK, given the discussion in the comments:

this is what a tweet looks like when it comes from twitter's streaming API after it is saved in mongodb, I've stripped some of the non-essential data out of the object to simplify the example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f2849353ac01aebf231408a"),
    "place" : null,
    "text" : "tweet text",
    "created_at" : "Tue Jan 31 20:04:05 +0000 2012",
    "retweet_count" : 0,
    "favorited" : false,
    "source" : "<a href=\"http://mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Mobile Web</a>",
    "in_reply_to_screen_name" : null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id" : null,
    "retweeted" : false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id" : null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : null,
    "id_str" : "123456767800304",
    "user" : {
    },
    "truncated" : false,
    "id" : NumberLong("1234567890"),
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str" : null,
    "entities" : {
        "hashtags" : [ ],
        "user_mentions" : [ ],
        "urls" : [ ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, each tweet is stored as a new tweet. If this was a re-tweet, it would have the retweeted flag set to true and have the id of the post it was a response to as well as the user it was in response to referenced in the top level fields.

Comment: if i undestand well your post, when a user click the "retweet" post, it creates a new post but with the retweeted:userid, so it takes the post body to create another post?